# Windows authentication and subscriptions in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I've got an ssrs report server setup and the data sources are set to use the user's windows login. However when I try to setup a subscription it says it can't because the credentials aren't stored in the data source. Is there no way to have a subscription that uses a generic account but when run interactively it uses Windows username

Answer (score 0):

I use a database account for running all of the reports. You'll have to set this up in each database. Then I have report folder permissions associated to Active Directory groups. I also use a domain service account for deploying the reports and setting up the subscriptions. That way if a member of the BI team leaves the company and their account is deactivated the subscription will still run.

Data Source Example:

[image]